# I'm trying to work with the BIS database in R but it's giving an error and it doesn't load the data

Tags: r

I'm trying to work with the BIS data in R but it's been giving numerous errors, I'll share here what's happening

```
library(BIS)
datasets <- get_datasets()
head(datasets, 20)
# A tibble: 20 × 2
   name                                            url  
   <chr>                                           <chr>
 1 Locational banking statistics                   http…
 2 Consolidated banking statistics                 http…
 3 Debt securities statistics                      http…
 4 Credit to the non-financial sector              http…
 5 Credit-to-GDP gaps                              http…
 6 Debt service ratios for the private non-financ… http…
 7 Global liquidity indicators                     http…
 8 Exchange-traded derivatives statistics          http…
 9 OTC derivatives outstanding                     http…
10 US dollar exchange rates (monthly, quarterly a… http…
11 US dollar exchange rates (daily, horizontal ti… http…
12 US dollar exchange rates (daily, vertical time… http…
13 Effective exchange rate indices (monthly)       http…
14 Effective exchange rate indices (daily, horizo… http…
15 Effective exchange rate indices (daily, vertic… http…
16 Triennial Survey statistics on turnover         http…
17 Property prices: selected series                http…
18 Property prices: long series                    http…
19 Payments and financial market infrastructures … http…
20 Payments and financial market infrastructures … http…

Debt_service <- get_bis(datasets$url[6])
trying URL 'https://www.bis.org/statistics/full_dsr_csv.zip'
downloaded 9248 bytes

Rows: 67 Columns: 102                                                                      
── Column specification ────────────────────────────────
Delimiter: ","
chr (102): X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9, X10, ...

ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
Rows: 66 Columns: 102                                                                      
── Column specification ────────────────────────────────
Delimiter: ","
chr  (9): FREQ, Frequency, BORROWERS_CTY, Borrowers'...
dbl (93): DECIMALS, 1999-Q1, 1999-Q2, 1999-Q3, 1999-...

ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
```

oh this error comes to me

Comment: What error are you getting? I don't see an error message here. This is just some basic info about the data import. Does `Debt_service` not contain the data you want?

Comment: glimpse(Debt_service)
 'try-error' chr "Error in dplyr::select(df, -time_period) : \n  Can't subset columns that don't exist.\n\033[31m✖\033[39m Column"| __truncated__
 - attr(*, "condition")=List of 9

Comment: The [BIS package has been removed from CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/package=BIS) thus its hard to reproduce the error. There may be other problems with the package which is why it was removed.